# What's the difference between @Property and { fields } in objective c?

Tags: objective-c

I am a C# programmer and now I have started to learn Objective-c, I have some questions at the very beginning. I was trying to follow the tutorials, so here I met the first question as the title says.

My purpose is to define some properties as so-called like in the C#, I would like to give a C# language sample, it would be like this.

```
public class Person
{
   public string name {get;set;}
   public int age  {get;set;}
}
```

so here I found two ways for the implementation.

1.

```
@interface Person : NSObject

@property NSString *name;
@property int age;

@end
```

2.

```
@interface Person : NSObject
{
    NSString *name;
    int age;
}

@end
```

I am eager to figure out what is the difference.

Thanks a lot,

Comment: In first one they are properties; in second one, they are iVars (no getter/setter)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your second interface would translate to C# as follows:

```
class Person {
    string name;
    int age;
}
```

In other words, instance variables are similar to C#'s fields, while properties are very similar to C#'s properties. The biggest difference between "automatic" properties of C# and properties of Objective C is that in C# it's "all or nothing": you either make the property automatic, or declare a variable for it. On Objective C, you can have an auto-generated getter, and a manually written setter (or the other way around).

Answer (score 1):

With the second one you are only creating instance variables.
`@property` automatically generates you these as their associated getter and setter methods.